# Is there a way to send unselected datas to the controller directly?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've a form with a `ChoiceType` field and I need to do something with selected datas AND something else with not selected datas.

I think I need to retrieve unselected datas with using the selected datas but is there a way to send them to the controller directly ? Maybe with `empty_data` but I'm not sure to understand how to use it.

To clarify if I have it in the vue :

```
<select name="carlist" form="carform" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I retrieve "audi" and "opel" values using `$form->getData()` ? ( if it's possible of course )

Answer (score 1):

If field is part of your form object (`$form` in this example), to retrieve the data for your field `carlist` you can use:

```
$carlist = $form->get('carlist');
```

Or, to get the data from the entire form you can use: `$data = $form->getData()`.

If your field is **not part** of your form object you can use:

```
$carlist = $request->request->get('carlist');
```

What this does is get the data from the [Request object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object).

Answer (score 1):

You have a form, something like this:

```
<select name="carlist" form="carform" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Your controller:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(YourForm::class, //...);

    $choices = [
        'Volvo' => 'volvo',
        'Saab'  => 'saab',
        'Opel'  => 'opel',
        'Audi'  => 'audi',
    ];
    $form->add('carlist', ChoiceType::class, [
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices' => $choices
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $not_used_cars = [];
        $car_list = $form->get('carlist')->getData();
        foreach ($choices as $car) {
            if ( false === array_search( $car, $car_list ) )
                $not_used_cars[] = $car;
        }
        /*
         * dump($not_used_cars);
         * //Output:
         * [
         *      0 => 'opel'
         *      1 => 'audi'
         * ]
         */
    }
```